# Django: Nested for loop do not work properly

Tags: python, html, django

We have two tables that have many to one relationships.

in models.py :

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    CATEGOTY = (
        ('programming', 'programming'),
        ('other', 'other')
    )

    title    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    content  = models.TextField(null=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGOTY, null=False)
    creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author   = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and in views.py:

```py
def articles(request):
    authors                = Author.objects.all()
    articles               = Article.objects.all()
    totalArticles          = articles.count()
    authorAticles = Author.objects.annotate(numberOfArticles=Count('article'))

    return render(request, 'articles/article.html', {
        'articles'     : articles,
        'authors'      : authors,
        'totalArticles': totalArticles,
        'authorAticles': authorAticles
        })
```

and html code:

```html
<div class="container mb-3 p-3" id="author-aricle">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            totle articles: {{totalArticles}}
        </div>
        {% for author in  authors %}
            <div class="col-sm">
                {{author}}: 
                {% for authorAticle in authorAticles %}
                    {{authorAticle.numberOfArticles}}
                {% endfor %}
                articles
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the html output to display the number of articles by each author next to its name
This means how many articles does each author have?
I want the html output to be like this:

author1: 2 articles

author2: 3 articles

author3: 3 articles

etc

but this does not happen and the output is:

author1: 3 3 2 articles

author2: 3 3 2 articles

author3: 3 3 2 articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `authorAticles = Author.objects.annotate(numberOfArticles=Count('article'))` returns Authors, not Articles, nor count of them.
So later on here:

```
{{author}}: 
{% for authorAticle in authorAticles %}
```

For each author, you iterate over all of authors.

Something like `{{ author.article_set.count }}` should work to count all of them for each author.

Or if you prefer to use annotate just add it to author filtering:

```
authors = Author.objects.annotate(numberOfArticles=Count('article'))
```

and then refer to it in template:

```
{{ author }}:
{{ author.numberOfArticles }}
```